# Como passar argumentos ao executar programa pelo Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Este código no notepadd ++ funcionava porque na linha de comandos adicionava o porto exemplo 5000,6000 etc. Mas no netbeans não dá para fazer isso. Por isso tenho aqui o codigo do cliente e servidor. Troca de mensagens,

ClienteTCP.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClienteTCP {

   public static void main(String argv[]) 
    {
        try 
        {
            // criação do socket TCP de ligação ao servidor, o 1º argumento
            // é o nome da máquina, o 2º é o número do porto
            Socket sd = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(argv[0]),(new Integer(argv[1])).intValue());
            // obtenção dos canais de leitura e escrita do socket
            InputStream in = sd.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = sd.getOutputStream();
            // criação do buffer para envio e recepção de informação
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            for (;;) {
            // pede a mensagem ao utilizador
            System.out.print("Introduza a mensagem: ");
            System.out.flush();
            int length = System.in.read(buffer);
            // envia ao servidor o buffer através do outputstream
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            out.flush();
            // se premiu return, fecho da ligação
            if (length == 1) break;
            // leitura da mensagem ecoada pelo servidor
            length = in.read(buffer);
            System.out.println(new String(buffer,0,0,length));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // Surgiu algum problema com a ligação ao socket
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("ligação fechada");
    }
}
```

ServidorSimples.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ServidorSimples {

    /**
     * @param argv the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String argv[]) 
    {

        // obtem o número do porto da linha de comandos. Se não for especificado 
        // um porto o sistema operativo vai escolher automaticamenteum (porto 0)
        int listenPort= (argv.length == 0) ? 0 : (new Integer(argv[0])).intValue();
        ServerSocket SocketEscuta= null;
        InputStream in= null; 
        OutputStream out= null;
        Socket s= null; 
        try 
        {
            SocketEscuta = new ServerSocket(listenPort);
            s = SocketEscuta.accept();
            System.out.println("Ligação estabelecida"); 
            // criação do buffer para receber informação
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            // obtenção dos canais de leitura e escrita para o novo
            // socket estabelecido
            in = s.getInputStream(); 
            out = s.getOutputStream();
            for (;;) 
            { 
                // Leitura da informação do socket
                int length = in.read(buffer);
                // se apenas return foi lido, fecha a ligação 
                if (length == 1) break;
                // escreve a mensagem no ecrã e devolve-a ao cliente
                System.out.println(new String(buffer,0,0,length));
                out.write(buffer,0,length);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            // Ocorreu algum problema na recepção ou envio de informação
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Ligação fechada"); 
    }

}
```

A minha dúvida e correr o programa no netbeans 
Dá erro nesta linha:
Socket sd = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(argv[0]),(new Integer(argv[1])).intValue());

parece que no netbeans não permite escolher o porto.

No notepadd++:
javac ServidorSimples.java
java ServidorSimples 1234

Nova janela cliente:
java ClienteTCP localhost 1234

E funciona!

mas queria que o netbeans permitise escolher o porto
tipo isto: connection   = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 5320 );

ou isto
server = new ServerSocket(5320,2);

mas alterar de modo a que funcione no codigo do cliente linha 12:

Tem aqui um link com duvida parecida: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762205/why-am-i-getting-an-error-when-i-try-to-run-my-socket-program-in-java 
De qualquer modo o meu codigo difere um pouco. 
Mas a linha e a mesma.

Comment: E qual é a sua dúvida? Algum erro? Explique melhor sua necessidade, formate sua pergunta também.

Comment: Tem razão não apresentava duvida aparente. Já editei o codigo.

Answer (score 3):

Para rodar seu arquivo no NetBeans passando argumentos você vai precisar instalar este plugin **[Run With Arguments](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53855/run-with-arguments)**.

Exemplo (após instalado):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

-

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.out.println(argv[0]);
    System.out.println(argv[1]);
}
```

Saída:

> arg1
>
> arg2

-

Fora isso você vai ter que ou fixar os valores no código (**hardcode**) ou então rodar pelo cmd passando os argumentos.

Comment: Funciona! Ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 1):

Basta clicar com o botão direito sobre o projeto e então escolher **Propriedades**.

[image: projeto]

Na janela seguinte, na aba **Executar** você pode inserir os argumentos de inicialização:

[image: propriedades]

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args)); // [foo, bar, baz] 
    }
}
```